# Append a javascript variable to url

Tags: javascript

I am calling a url from javascript. I want to append my javascript variable as a parameter.

I tried following but its not working. The name is the parameter that has issue

```
var name='myName';

var url = '<%=request.getContextPath()%>/wizards/script/add_script_wizard1.faces?organizationKey=<%=request.getAttribute("organizationKey")%>& name=+name+';
```

Please help

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the space between the ampersand and the variable name 'name'

```
var name='myName';
var url = '<%=request.getContextPath()%>/wizards/script/add_script_wizard1.faces?organizationKey=<%=request.getAttribute("organizationKey")%>&name='+name;
```

Comment: This will not append the variable

Comment: It sure looks like it does to me @Bart.